# SBT publish is not uploading jar file to artifactory (publish) java.io.IOException: PUT operation to URL failed with status code 400: Bad Request

Tags: scala, sbt, artifactory

I've below `build.sbt` file

```
    name := "tads-akka-cluster-events"
    organization := "technorati"
    version := "0.0.3"
    scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
    crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.12.9", "2.13.0")
    publishMavenStyle := true

    PB.targets in Compile := Seq(
    scalapb.gen() -> (sourceManaged in Compile).value
    )

    libraryDependencies += "com.thesamet.scalapb" %% "scalapb-runtime" % scalapb.compiler.Version.scalapbVersion % "protobuf"

    credentials += Credentials("Artifactory Realm", "artifactory.svcs.opal.synacor.com", "admin", "password")

    publishTo := {
    val nexus = "http://artifactory.svcs.opal.synacor.com/"
    if (isSnapshot.value)
        Some("repository.synacor.com-snapshots" at nexus + "artifactory/synacor-local")
    else
        Some("repository.synacor.com-releases"  at nexus + "artifactory/synacor-local")
    }
```

When I did `sbt publish`, I get below error -

```
    sbt:tads-akka-cluster-events> publish
    [info] Packaging /Users/rajkumar.natarajan/Documents/Coding/misc/tads-akka-cluster-events/target/scala-2.11/tads-akka-cluster-events_2.11-0.0.3-sources.jar ...
    [info] Done packaging.
    [info] Wrote /Users/rajkumar.natarajan/Documents/Coding/misc/tads-akka-cluster-events/target/scala-2.11/tads-akka-cluster-events_2.11-0.0.3.pom
    [info] Updating ...
    [info] Done updating.
    [info] Packaging /Users/rajkumar.natarajan/Documents/Coding/misc/tads-akka-cluster-events/target/scala-2.11/tads-akka-cluster-events_2.11-0.0.3.jar ...
    [info] Packaging /Users/rajkumar.natarajan/Documents/Coding/misc/tads-akka-cluster-events/target/scala-2.11/tads-akka-cluster-events_2.11-0.0.3-javadoc.jar ...
    [info] Done packaging.
    [info] Done packaging.
    [info]  published tads-akka-cluster-events_2.11 to http://artifactory.svcs.opal.synacor.com/artifactory/synacor-local/technorati/tads-akka-cluster-events_2.11/0.0.3/tads-akka-cluster-events_2.11-0.0.3.pom
    [error] java.io.IOException: PUT operation to URL http://artifactory.svcs.opal.synacor.com/artifactory/synacor-local/technorati/tads-akka-cluster-events_2.11/0.0.3/tads-akka-cluster-events_2.11-0.0.3.jar failed with status code 400: Bad Request
    [error]         at org.apache.ivy.util.url.AbstractURLHandler.validatePutStatusCode(AbstractURLHandler.java:82)
    [error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.ivyint.GigahorseUrlHandler.upload(GigahorseUrlHandler.scala:191)
    [error]         at org.apache.ivy.util.url.URLHandlerDispatcher.upload(URLHandlerDispatcher.java:82)
    [error]         at org.apache.ivy.util.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:150)
    [error]         at org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.url.URLRepository.put(URLRepository.java:84)
    [error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.ConvertResolver$LocalIfFileRepo.put(ConvertResolver.scala:366)
    [error]         at org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.AbstractRepository.put(AbstractRepository.java:130)
    [error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.ConvertResolver$ChecksumFriendlyURLResolver.put(ConvertResolver.scala:118)
    [error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.ConvertResolver$ChecksumFriendlyURLResolver.put$(ConvertResolver.scala:105)
    [error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.ConvertResolver$$anonfun$defaultConvert$lzycompute$1$PluginCapableResolver$1.put(ConvertResolver.scala:165)
    [error]         at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.RepositoryResolver.publish(RepositoryResolver.java:216)
    [error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$publish$5(IvyActions.scala:497)
    [error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$publish$5$adapted(IvyActions.scala:496)
    [error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.$anonfun$foreach$1(TraversableLike.scala:788)
    [error]         at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:937)
    [error]         at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:937)
    [error]         at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1425)
    [error]         at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:70)
    [error]         at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:69)
    [error]         at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    [error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:787)
    [error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.publish(IvyActions.scala:496)
    [error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$publish$3(IvyActions.scala:144)
    [error]         at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
    [error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.withChecksums(IvyActions.scala:157)
    [error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.withChecksums(IvyActions.scala:151)
    [error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$publish$1(IvyActions.scala:144)
    [error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$publish$1$adapted(IvyActions.scala:134)
    [error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.$anonfun$withModule$1(Ivy.scala:239)
    [error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.$anonfun$withIvy$1(Ivy.scala:204)
    [error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.sbt$internal$librarymanagement$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:70)
    [error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:77)
    [error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:95)
    [error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:80)
    [error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:99)
    [error]         at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    [error]         at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    [error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:60)
    [error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:50)
    [error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    [error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    [error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:77)
    [error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:199)
    [error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:196)
    [error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:238)
    [error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.publish(IvyActions.scala:134)
    [error]         at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$publishTask$4(Defaults.scala:2416)
    [error]         at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$publishTask$4$adapted(Defaults.scala:2416)
    [error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
    [error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    [error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:67)
    [error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:269)
    [error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
    [error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:278)
    [error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:269)
    [error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:178)
    [error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:37)
    [error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    [error]         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    [error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    [error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    [error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    [error]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    [error] (publish) java.io.IOException: PUT operation to URL http://artifactory.svcs.opal.synacor.com/artifactory/synacor-local/technorati/tads-akka-cluster-events_2.11/0.0.3/tads-akka-cluster-events_2.11-0.0.3.jar failed with status code 400: Bad Request
    [error] Total time: 2 s, completed Sep 3, 2019 4:12:46 PM
    sbt:tads-akka-cluster-events>
```

When I checked the repository I see pom, pom.md5 and pom.sha1. 
But it is missing jar, jar.md5 and jar.sha1.
[image: repository missing jar]

Why I'm getting this error? What I'm missing and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forbidden Error with configuration \`publishConfiguration := publishConfiguration.value.withOverwrite(true)\` in SBT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57778153/forbidden-error-with-configuration-publishconfiguration-publishconfiguration)

Comment: @J0HN - This is not the duplicate. Please see the issues I mentioned in both the post are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've to add the setting `updateOptions := updateOptions.value.withGigahorse(false)` or run sbt like `sbt  -Dsbt.gigahorse=false clean publish`.

For more details please see this [github sbt issue](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3570).